# What $q.defer() really does?

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, q

I'm learning about Angular JS and on the moment I'm trying to understand about promises and async programming and I have this doubt about `$q.defer()`. My point is the following: usually when people work with promises they do something like that, considering that $q is already available

```
function someAsyncFunction() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    /* Do things and if everything goes fine return deferred.resolve(result) 
       otherwise returns deferred.reject()
     */

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

What is this really doing? When we do `var deferred = $q.defer()` it imediately switches all the execution of that function to another thread and return the promise being a reference to the results of this operation that is still performing there?

Is this the way we should think about when creating async methods?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded (excluding web workers)

Comment: Very good explanation given in AngularJS API for $q  [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

With $q u run functions asynchronously. 
Deferred objects signals that something, some task is done.

`var defer = $q.defer();` `// we create deferred object, which will finish later.`

```
defer.promise // we get access to result of the deferred task

.then( // .then() calls success or error callback
    function(param) {
        alert("i something promised " + param);
        return "something";
    }); // u can use 1 or more .then calls in row

 defer.resolve("call"); //returns promise
```

Here example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nalyvajko/HB7LU/29048/

Answer (score 0):

Angular's `$q` service is based on the Javascript library `Q`. You can read more about it in the [Q documentation](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/), or read the code in the [github repo](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). I think this part snipped from the introduction to the documentation explains it best:

> If a function cannot return a value or throw an exception without
>   blocking, it can return a promise instead. A promise is an object that
>   represents the return value or the thrown exception that the function
>   may eventually provide. A promise can also be used as a proxy for a
>   remote object to overcome latency.