# alexa say is not working with promise, rest and dynamodb combination

Tags: node.js, promise, alexa-skills-kit

I have an issue with my alexa app.  I am fairly new with NodeJS and Alexa,

Here is my issue.  I have a dynamodb that contains an array.  From that array, I will go and get all my values from a rest website that will provide me with JSON data.  I will pass this data to a template and finally call the alexa say command.

For some reason, everything works well, except for the say part.

I would definitely like that you shed some light on what I am missing.

Here is the code:

```
    app.intent('sayStockList', {
        'utterances': ['{|say stock list}']
      },
      function(req, res) {
        var stockInfoHelper = new StockInfoDataHelper();
        var currentUserId = req.userId;
        databaseHelper.readCodeList(currentUserId).then(function(currentJsonData) {
          var currentData = [];
          var toSay = '';
          console.log("1) Current Data= %j", currentJsonData);
          if (undefined === currentJsonData) {
            toSay = 'You don\'t have any code stored. To store a code say: Alexa, add code.';
          } else {
            currentData = currentJsonData['data'];
            return Promise.all(currentData.map(fn)).then(function(returnString) { //fn all return correctly
              console.log("2) Promise return : %s", returnString);
              res.say(returnString.toString()).shouldEndSession(false).send();
            }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log("3) Error: %s", err);
            });
          }
        }); // Promise readCodeList then end
        console.log("4) TEST 12 ");
        return true;
      }
    );// end app intent
```

This is the log output:

```
    4) TEST 12 
    1) Current Data= {"data":["data1","data2"],"userId":"xxxxxx"}
    Function getDataValue
    Function getDataValue
    2) Promise return : Return value for data1.  Return value for data2
```

Thanks for your help!

Ian-Rémi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the understanding that ...

- the `app.intent` callback should return `<promise>`, not `true`
- the `You don\'t have any code stored ...` message shouldn't be left hanging

... the following rewrite would make more sense :

```
app.intent('sayStockList', {
    'utterances': ['{|say stock list}']
}, function(req, res) {
    return databaseHelper.readCodeList(req.userId)
//  ^^^^^^
    .then(function(currentJsonData) {
        console.log("1) Current Data= %j", currentJsonData || null);
        if (!currentJsonData || !currentJsonData.data || currentJsonData.data.length === 0) { // better safety
            return 'You don\'t have any code stored. To store a code say: Alexa, add code.';
        //  ^^^^^^
        } else {
            return Promise.all(currentJsonData.data.map(fn))
            .then(function(results) {
                console.log("2) Promise return : %s", results.toString());
                return results.toString();
            //  ^^^^^^
            });
        }
    })
    .then(function(sayString) { // `sayString` is either the results or the `'You don\'t have any code stored. ...'` message.
        res.say(sayString).shouldEndSession(false).send();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("3) Error: %s", err);
        res.say('Sorry, something went wrong').shouldEndSession(false).send(); // keep user informed.
    });
}); // end app intent
```

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888, I'll try that this evening!

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I'm interested in this stuff.

Comment: Could not wait till this evening...   It works great and definitely a lot cleaner...  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solution to the promise.

From what I have understood, the res.say action was consumed before the promise was fulfilled.  Using the Q framework, I was able to delay the consumption of the res.say after the promise.  (Not sure I have the correct vocabulary here, feel free to correct me!)

Also, please feel free to let me know if you would have done anything differently.

Here is the corrected code

```
var q = require('q');
```

...

```
app.intent('sayStockList', {
    'utterances': ['{|say stock list}']
    },
      function(req, res) {
          var stockInfoHelper = new StockInfoDataHelper();
          var currentUserId = req.userId;
          var qPromise = q.defer(); //  <--  Added this line here
          databaseHelper.readCodeList(currentUserId).then(function(currentJsonData) {
              var currentData = [];
              var toSay = '';
              console.log("1) Current Data= %j", currentJsonData);
              if (undefined === currentJsonData) {
                  toSay = 'You don\'t have any code stored. To store a code say: Alexa, add code.';
              } else {
                  currentData = currentJsonData['data'];
                  return Promise.all(currentData.map(fn)).then(function(returnString) { //fn all return correctly
                      console.log("2) Promise return : %s", returnString);
                      res.say(returnString.toString()).shouldEndSession(false).send();
                      qPromise.resolve();  // <--  When this is called, the res.say is working
                  }).catch(function(err) {
                      console.log("3) Error: %s", err);
                  });
              }
          }); // Promise readCodeList then end
          console.log("4) TEST 12 ");
          return qPromise.promise; <--- From my understanding, this is added to make the alexa app wait for the promise resolve.  
      }
    );// end app intent
```

A little bit more information in here
[What $q.defer() really does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121472/what-q-defer-really-does)

You can also read on the q documentation here : 

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

http://devdocs.io/q/

Fadeout79

Comment: Not self-explanatory. For the benefit of others (and to satisfy my curiosity), could you add the working code please.

Comment: @Roamer-1888, I have added the code in my answer, and provided a little bit more information (not yet a specialist with Q nor any other of the subject)

Comment: That kinda makes sense in that that you now return `qPromise.promise` instead of `true`, and `qPromise` gets resolved once `returnString` is available. But I'm sure it can be written better. Give me a moment and I'll post an answer.